# Save XML response to file with formatting

Tags: xml, soap, pretty-print

I am making a SOAP request to a webservice and are receiving an XML response. Currently I am saving this XML into a file which works fine, but the XML looks like a mess, no linebreaks and indents.
See this example in one line:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><soap:Body><SoegPersonRegistreringCprResponse xmlns="http://webservices.rki.dk/"><SoegPersonRegistreringCprResult><Error xmlns="http://webservices.rki.dk"><Code>101</Code><Text>Generel fejl</Text><Detailed>InternWS.Common.Exceptions.InternWSException: Generel fejl</Detailed></Error></SoegPersonRegistreringCprResult></SoegPersonRegistreringCprResponse></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

In editor it looks like this: [image]

Is it possible to save this XML into file and keep the nice formatting like it has in browsers. See this example: [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Notepad++, you can use the [XML Tools](http://sourceforge.net/projects/npp-plugins/files/) plugin to prettify your XML file.

Note that the original file, without indents and line breaks, is still *valid* XML, even though it is less human-readable.